# Printing array using loops give garbage values but printing individually gives correct values

Tags: c, arrays

I've only picked up C programming 2 months ago and I'm self taught from reading books. So if there are any bad habits or things that I can do to improve coding in C, I'll appreciate greatly if you guys can feedback to me.

I'm currently learning how to write standard input and output for arrays. The following is a program I wrote to accept input for an array from the user and then printing it out using loops to test whether my input was successful. I also printed out the first three element individually in the middle to test whether my input was succesfull.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long length;
    long i;
    long N;
    long arr[length];

    printf("length of array: ");
    scanf("%ld", &length);
    printf("input %ld elements in the array: ", length);

    N = length;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
    scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%ld", arr[0]);
    printf("\n%ld", arr[1]);
    printf("\n%ld\n", arr[2]);

    printf("Array:");

    for(i=0;  i < N; i += 1) {
    printf("%ld", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I got garbage value when printing out the third element individually and also got garbage value when printing out the second and third element using loop.

```
length of array: 3
input 3 elements in the array: 1
2
3

1
2
8589934595
Array:1515396075588589934594
```

I've tried to debug the code by searching on the internet for a week already, but none of the answer seems to be able to help me fix this problem. I cannot continue coding array if I can't even input and output from the user. Please help me find out what's the issue with my code.

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with Javascript nor HTML...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array arr is not defined correctly and hence it starts to print garbage value.

This was the output I got with your code.
[your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJs3k.jpg)

Here is the solution which  tried

```
    long length;
long i;
long N;


printf("length of array: ");
scanf("%ld", &length);
printf("input %ld elements in the array: ", length);

N = length;
long arr[length];
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
    scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
}

printf("\n%ld", arr[0]);
printf("\n%ld", arr[1]);
printf("\n%ld\n", arr[2]);

printf("Array:");

for(i=0;  i < N; i +=1) {
    printf("%ld", arr[i]);
}

return 0;
```

And the output I got was 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irKbQ.jpg)

You can see that I declared the variable long arr[length] after the user inputs the length.

So the solution is, just move the code in line number 8 to 15

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the declaration

```
long arr[length];
```

*after* you get the value of `length` from the user. You're using the uninitialized value of `length` as the size of the array.

```
long length;
long i;
long N;

printf("length of array: ");
scanf("%ld", &length);
printf("input %ld elements in the array: ", length);

long arr[length];
```